# Threaded WCF Client on basicHtppBinding slow

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, wcf, task

I have a problem using WCF in a multi-threaded environment.

I am running 120 Tasks, each using an castle injected singleton instance of the WCF client. The Client is hosted as Windows Service.

**Goal**

350+ API calls in 1 second having a response time of 200-250ms.

**Service installer**

`container.Register(Component.For<IMyWcfClient>().ImplementedBy<MyWcfClient>().LifestyleSingleton());`

**Task**

```
public class A
{
     private client;

     public A(IMyWcfClient client)
     {
          this.client = client;
     }

     public void Call()
     {
          client.MyMethod();  //takes up to 25 seconds
     }
}
```

Now when I am creating 120 Tasks to call my method in parallel, I run into performance problems.

Each call takes ~25s, whereas the time spend on the network is around 250ms.
I don't understand where I loose the 24,8s?? How can I speed up the performance. Fyi, if I test with only 60 threads I don't see this latency.

WCF diagnostics:

Activity Boundary: 11:01:32

A Message was written: 11:01:56

Sent a message over a channel: 11:01:56

....

Activity Boundary: 11:01:56

Comment: Why share `client` as a Singleton, and what is `IMyWcfClient` is it a WCF proxy generated by adding a service reference.  What's the performance like using `ChannelFactory`

Comment: - Singleton as I thought it might be resource saving as of 350 calls / sec.
- Yes, it's a WCF proxy
- ChannelFactory not yet tested. (todo)

Comment: Perhaps test that assumption first, it might not be correct place to make optimizations.  I've never tried using the proxies as singletons, but I doubt they are coded to be used in such a fashion.  You might find just creating the Channels with `ChannelRFactory` suffices